# About if x is int

Tags: python

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if  next is int:
        if next < 50:
            print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
            exit(0)
        else:
             dead("You greedy bastard!")
    else:
        print "Man,you need to learn how to print a number!"
def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

gold_room()
```

whatever integer I input,always turns out that"Man,you need to learn how to print a number".
Why the first if doesn't work? Thank you guys!

Comment: next is a string and `if  next is int` is not how to test for an int

Comment: source of the code: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

Comment: Continuing from what aberna said: I think solving question 5 from the study drills below the exercise will answer your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, you can use str.isdigit to check if a string contains only digits but it will fail for negative numbers:

```
nxt = raw_input("> ")
if nxt.isdigit(): # str.isdigit
    if int(nxt) < 50:
```

The best way to do what you want is to use a try/except

```
while True:
    nxt = raw_input("> ")
    try: 
        nxt = int(nxt) 
        break # break if we got valid input that can be cat
    except ValueError: # else we get here and print our message and go back to start again
        print("Man,you need to learn how to print a number!")
        continue
if nxt < 50: # if we get here we got valid input from the potentially greedy  b!*!*!*d!"
   print("Nice, you're not greedy, you win!")
   return 
dead("You greedy b!*!*!*d!") # we don't need an else as if previous statement in True we will have exited the function
```

So in your function:

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"
    while True:
        nxt = raw_input("> ")
        try:
            nxt = int(nxt)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Man,you need to learn how to print a number!")
            continue
    if nxt < 50:
        print("Nice, you're not greedy, you win!")
        return       
    dead("You greedy b!*!*!*d!")
```

I would not use `next` as a variable name as it shadows the builtin function  python function next.

If you did ever want to check the type of an object you would use isinstance:

```
if isinstance(object,type):
```

Comment: We must write a small note to OP stating that `!@#$%` is how we represent such words! :D

Answer (score 2):

raw_input returns a string.

```
xin = raw_input("> ")
try:
    x = int(xin)
except ValueError:
    print "xin is not an int"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use try excepts for this

```
try:
    if int(next) < 50:
        ...
    else:
        ...
except ValueError as e:
    #handle error
```

This attempts to cast the string to an integer if it can't be done i.e. not a number then it will enter the exception block